# Team Foundation Build 2010 - Find changes since last good build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using Team Foundation Build 2010 for my build process. I want to update the file version for assemblies which have changed since the last good build. How can I determine which files have changed since the last good build? My builds are labeled, but they do not have associated change sets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using a "file by file" labelling because it will become very difficult to maintain really fast.

What I do now is the following:

- All project refers to a common AssemblyVersion.cs file that contains only the information for the DLL and Exe version
- In the development environment this file has a fixed x.y.z.0 version number, where x, y and z are the numbers of the current major, minor and revision version of my products
- During the build the common AssemblyVersion.cs file is changed so that the 0 is replaced with a 5 digit number (less that 65535) that is generated starting from the current date and the build number for the day. The same number is automatically applied as a label to TFS

In this way:

- All assemblies made on development machines have a .0 build number and could be easily identified and, if you need to copy a DLL from one developer machine to another the version is correct
- All the file that makes a product has a specific build number that can be used to track the specific label on TFS if needed